# UnauthorizedAccessException on creating file after deletion using FileStream

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, filestream, file-access

I am facing an issue on client system. On trying to reproduce it in a sample code I have reproduced it.

Here's the sample code

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private _lock As New Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf createFile)
        With t
            .IsBackground = True
            .Name = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
            .Start()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub createFile()
        Dim path As String = "D:\SomeFile.txt"

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            SyncLock _lock
                If File.Exists(path) Then File.Delete(path)

                Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew)

                End Using
            End SyncLock    
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just Run this code and click the button 3-4 times and notice the exception as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

The stacktrace of this exception is:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled   Message=Access to
>   the path 'D:\SomeFile.txt' is denied.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
>   options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>          at WindowsApplication1.Form1.createFile() in C:\Users\premjeet.singh\Desktop\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line
>   23
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Can anybody let me know the reason for this UnauthorizedAccessException exception as the file is already deleted before creating the new one and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty normal, you are doing battle with other processes that run on your machine that are also interested in the file.  Better known as "anti-malware" and "search indexer".  The "click 3 times" scenario is just the failure-mode you induce by those other processes taking a while to have a look-see at the file content.

Such processes will open the file for delete sharing to minimize their impact.  Same capability is exposed in .NET, [FileShare.Delete option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That works, to a degree, you don't have any trouble deleting the file as you found out.  But the file will not actually disappear from the file system until those other processes close their handle on the file.  While it still exists, any process that tries to open or overwrite the pending-delete file will be slapped with an "access denied" error.

In general, you *never* want to use the approach you use now, deleting the file and then trying to recreate it.  Given the considerable odds that this can fail, you'll leave the user with no file at all.  That's irrecoverable loss of data.  The alternative is to *swap* the file, supported by the [File.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  method.  Which works well for locked files, these processes only have a lock on the file data, not on the directory entry.  In other words, you can *rename* the file without trouble.

```
Private Function createFile(ByVal outpath As String) As Boolean
    Dim temp As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(outpath), Guid.NewGuid.ToString())
    Dim bak As String = outpath + ".bak"
    '' Create the file first
    Using fs As New FileStream(temp, FileMode.CreateNew)
        ''...
    End Using
    '' Now try to swap it in place
    Try
        File.Delete(bak)
        File.Replace(temp, outpath, bak)
    Catch
        File.Delete(temp)
        Return False
    End Try
    '' That worked, don't need the backup anymore.  Failure to delete is not fatal
    Try
        File.Delete(bak)
    Catch
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

This still isn't perfect but the odds for data loss are eliminated and you give the process that is holding on the file more time to finish using it.  Whether you want to put a retry-loop around the swap operation is up to you.

Technically it is possible to make it perfect, you have to give the backup filename a random name so you can never fail to delete it the next time you create the file.  That however sprays files to the disk that are hard to get rid of.  If you do this then you must also move the file to the drive's Recycle Bin so it will get deleted *some* day in the future.  Luckily that's easy to do in VB.NET, use the [DeleteFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helper function and specify RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin.  But only appropriate if you save to a local drive.

Comment: This seems to be the real explanation for the problem, thanks a lot Hans the Great... :)

Answer (score -4):

When you invoke `File.Delete(path)`, you must give the CPU some time to finish deleting the file before coming back to execute any further code that might have anything to do with the same file name as the one just deleted.

Several ways can accomplish the same thing. Here is how I would do it:

```
...
If File.Exists(path) Then
   File.Delete(path)

   Application.DoEvents()   'Force completing any pending events 
                            'immediately start deleting the file

   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)     'optional: wait 1 second

   While System.IO.File.Exists(path)   'In case the file is still in 
                                       ' the process of being deleted
                                       ' Wait here for it to finish
   End While


   Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew)    'Now create the file

End If
....
```

Comment: Why an explicit wait to check the file is deleted? It's not a good coding practice to use Thread.Sleep or an infinite loop, Instead why File.Delete is not waiting itself till the deletion is complete?

Comment: A couple of things I'd like to mention for your benefit, recommending [Application.DoEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/495455) is almost always a bad idea. Without a try catch users have a higher chance of seeing the problem: **UnauthorizedAccessException** and under unique circumstances (I admit very, very rarely depending on HDD/NAS, anti-virus, file locking, etc) could potentially result in the code getting trapped in the `while` loop resulting in a frozen application.